# How to change the color of text and/or background in Chrome regardless of dark mode or light mode

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having an issue where in dark mode my button text is displaying as white on top of bright green. I can change the color to any light color no problem, but if I select a dark color,  Chrome automatically displays it as light/white regardless. Even when manually setting the CSS to "black !important".

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippets.